# How do I remove the write-protection from the sda5 disk after crash?

Tags: fsck, read-only

I run the `fsck` command and even booted by PC in recovery mode. I still can't change the write protection.

Need help here.

Comment: Please edit your question to show us how you are determining that the partition is write-protected.

Comment: Clarify. What is write protected exactly? Show output of `mount` and `cat /etc/fstab`. How did you run fsck and what did it tell you?

Answer (score 0):

If your write-protect issue is because of software's problems the low level utilities like hdparm can solve your issue:

```
sudo hdparm -r0 /dev/sda5
```

But if you can't write on your hdd because of somethings like stress ‚ fire ‚strike ‚ ... (Physically write-protected) We can't do any things.